# Using highcharts/rounded-corners with Chartkick in Rails

Tags: highcharts

I am currently working on a Rail application using Chartkick to produce charts and highcharts as the backend library

I have been trying to figure out a way to use the "rounded-corners" highcharts plugin (https://github.com/highcharts/rounded-corners) but did not manage to find a way to enable it.

Has anyone been able to find a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try load `rounded-corners.js` module in that way:

```
import HighchartsRoundedCorners from 'highcharts/rounded-corners/master/rounded-corners'
```

EDIT

To adjust corners to round set following options:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderRadiusTopLeft: '50%',
        borderRadiusTopRight: '50%'
    }
},
```

Comment: But what do you do with that module? Just importing it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This plugin allows setting rounded corners for bar and column series.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I understand that. I mean how do you actually use this plugin, after importing it, to round the corners on a bar chart? We've imported it, but can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: In the answer above example config for javascript.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75463548/9154668) - how to initialize the module.