# How do you use highcharts-rounded-corners as an npm module?

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know how to actually use the [highcharts-rounded-corners](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-rounded-corners) npm module? The only examples in the repo use `<script>` tags on the page rather than the npm module, and the npm module itself has no examples.

Just importing the module doesn't work; treating it as a wrapper and passing the `Highcharts` module to it doesn't either... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a module, import and initialize it:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import HC_rounded from "highcharts-rounded-corners";

// init the module
HC_rounded(Highcharts);
```

**Official doc on how to use Highchart modules:**

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wjzbhd?file=index.js